# Centering with CSS Transform or Flexbox which one is better supported?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Centering with CSS transform like this

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

VS
Centering with Flexbox like this

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

Which one is better supported and which one is better and advisable?

Comment: CSS transform has better support, about which one, flexbox flows better, still, it depends on so many things...and is also primarily opinion-based

Comment: Apples and oranges. `absolute` removes an element from the flow of the page, and flex doesn't do that. That may or may not work for you. `transform` has better browser support than `flex`, but flex is pretty widely supported (~97% browser support at the moment). Use whichever one works for your requirements.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks man, you should put that as an answer.

Comment: @Jay roger that. Also put another solution in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apples and oranges. `absolute` removes an element from the flow of the page, and `flex` doesn't do that. That may or may not work for you. `transform` has better browser support than flex, but flex is pretty widely supported (~97% browser support at the moment). Browser support is the only reason I would use `absolute` with `transform` over `flex`.

You can also use `display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;` and do the same thing, and it has better support than either of the previous techniques. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table

Use whichever one works for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I use flexbox myself. Centering is just the first awesome thing it can do. See [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) for more options: reversing, wrapping, spacing, and more. To verify the support for any CSS, [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) is an excellent resource.