# Text not centered in div

Tags: css, html

```css
* {margin: 0;}
   
div {
  background-color:#bad455;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  position:fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align:center;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 50px 5px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:10%;
  transform:skewX(50deg);
}
div p {
  top:50%;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>oooo</p>
</div>
```

When I did `top:50%` and set the `position:relative` , I was expecting this text to go in the middle. But now I can see it isn't exactly in the middle of it. If someone could explain I would be grateful!

Comment: The top of the text is 50% from top, so the text isn't vertically centered

Answer (score 2):

Use   `transform: translateY(-50%);` to center it correctly

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: #bad455;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 50px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10%;
  transform: skewX(50deg);
}

div p {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>oooo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd say it's still not in the middle (at least in FF)

Comment: it was typo :( fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use flexbox (CSS3). So adding

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

To `div` centers the text.

```css
* {margin: 0;}
   
div {
  background-color:#bad455;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  position:fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 50px 5px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:10%;
  transform:skewX(50deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>oooo</p>
</div>
```

[See this discussion for comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595251/centering-with-css-transform-or-flexbox-which-one-is-better-supported)